# Using php to translate URL parameters to cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I have a web page that uses cookies.  I am trying to adapt it to process parameters that are on the URL.  I added the php shown below, but I the page shows up as containing only the DOCTYPE.

php is enabled and working within html pages (I have another page where I succesfully rewrite the META tag).  Seems to me this should work so I probably have a basic misunderstanding.  Can someone help?  Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
if ( $_GET("rID") == "auth" ){
   setcookie("rID","auth");  
   setcookie("authCode", $_GET("authCode"));  
   setcookie("GP_UID", $_GET("GP_UID"));  
}
?>
<html>
<head>...
```

Comment: `$_GET` is an array, not a function. You use square brackets `[` and `]` to access arrays and parenthesis to run a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
if ( $_GET("rID") == "auth" ){
          ^--- here
```

Should be:

```
if ( $_GET["rID"] == "auth" ){
```

Make sure you've got errors [turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) in development. PHP will tell you when you make an error.

Comment: Don't forget `$_GET("authCode")` and `$_GET("GP_UID")`.